# how to write a number to a file and then display information linked to it when entered into a console?

Tags: vb.net

I want the device information to be displayed whenever the case number is written into the console. the case number needs to be stored into a file and have the device information which was inputted with that case number be displayed whenever that specific number is imputed into the console. I think streamreader and streamwriter needs to be used but I am not sure how I would do it. here is the code

```
Imports System.IO
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim CaseNumber As Integer
    CaseNumber = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmddMMyy")
    Console.Write(CaseNumber)
    Console.WriteLine(" (this is your case number)")


    Console.WriteLine("If you would like to see the system data please enter the number you see above which is your case number")
    If Console.ReadLine = CaseNumber Then
        Console.WriteLine("DeviceInfo")
    End If
    deviceInfo()
End Sub

Sub deviceInfo()
    Console.WriteLine("what type of device?")
    Dim device As String = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine(device)
    Console.ReadKey() 'there would be more of this code which would have a full list of device information
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: ... What is being asked here? Where is device code read from?

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow is not a coding service, which makes this question [too broad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583). Do some research, go for trial and error, and return here when you bump into an actual problem.